# Draw A Reuleaux Triangle!

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, geometry

The [Reuleaux triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReuleauxTriangle.html) is the shape formed by the intersection of three circles, with each circle passing through the others' centers. Regardless of rotation, a Reuleaux triangle's width will always equal the radius of the circles:

[image: From Wolfram MathWorld]

<sub>Image: [Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReuleauxTriangle.html)</sub>

Write a program that takes a width `r` as input and displays a Reuleaux triangle of that width (in pixels).

You must display the shape in isolation, i.e. solid-filled, un-stroked, and over a solid-filled background.

[code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) - Shortest program in bytes wins.

Comment: Should the radius `r` be in pixels or just some scaling factor?

Comment: @Karl Napf Pixels.

Comment: Can we output anything to STDOUT, as long as we draw the Reuleaux triangle properly?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer That is fine.

Answer (score 21):

### JavaScript + HTML, <s>164</s> 158 + 13 = 171 bytes

```js
w=+prompt(f=(x,y)=>x*x+y*y<w*w);C.width=C.height=w*2;for(y=-w;++y<w;)for(x=-w;++x<w;)f(x,y)&f(w-x,y)&f(w/2-x,y-w*.866)&&C.getContext`2d`.fillRect(x+w,y+w,1,1)
```

```html
<canvas id=C>
```

I don't know why I enjoy answering these mathy drawing challenges with `<canvas>` so much...

Answer (score 13):

## Love2D, 320 bytes.

```lua
j=math.rad(60)i="increment"m=math s=m.sin C=m.cos g=love.graphics f="fill"S=g.stencil function love.draw()r=arg[2]c=function(x,y)return function()g.circle(f,x,y,r,r*4)end end X=r/2 Y=0 S(c(X,Y),i,1)S(c(X+C(j)*r,Y+s(j)*r),i,1,true)S(c(X-C(j)*r,Y+s(j)*r),i,1,true)g.setStencilTest("greater",2)g.rectangle(f,0,0,2*r,2*r)end
```

Probably not the optimal solution, it uses Love2D's stencils, setting up the 3 circles, and filling in over where they intersect.

Call via the command line, like `love tri.love 256`

### Example Output

[image]

Comment: It's quite lovely

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 111 bytes

```python
from turtle import*
r=input()
ht()
begin_fill()
c=circle
c(r,60)
seth(120)
c(r,60)
seth(240)
c(r,60)
end_fill()
```

[image: example run]

Answer (score 9):

### Mathematica <s>101</s> <s>100</s> 98 Bytes

Taking a different approach than @MichaelSeifert, and probably interpreting this a little more literally with regard to the pixel clause:

```
Image@Boole@Table[And@@(({x,y}∈#~Disk~2)&/@{{0,c=√3},d={1,0},-d}),{x,-1,1,2/#},{y,c-2,c,2/#}]&
```

Usage Example:

```
%@10
```

10 pixels
[image: 10 pixel image]

50 pixels
[image: 50 pixel image]

100 pixels
[image: 100 pixel image]

Saved a byte thanks to @MartinEnder (infix notation) and another 2 bytes by defining d.

Answer (score 7):

### PostScript, <s>96</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> <s>75</s> <s>73</s> 72 bytes

```
dup(^@^^Z<^@Z<){sin mul exch dup}forall
0 1 2{newpath 369 arc clip}for fill
```

Takes the input as a value on the stack. `^^` and `^@` represent literal control characters. `(^@^^Z<^@Z<)` is the string of characters with code points 0, 30, 90, 60, 0, 90, and 60, respectively. Those are then interpreted as angles in degrees, because obviously that’s what code points are for.

Saved 10 bytes because `closepath` isn’t needed (both `clip` and `fill` implicitly close the path).

Saved 1 byte by using `repeat` instead of defining a function.

Saved 10 bytes by switching to a completely different approach.

Saved 2 bytes by doing tricks with the stack.

Saved 1 byte by using `0 1 2{}for` instead of `3{}repeat`.

Answer (score 6):

### TeX/TikZ, <s>128</s> <s>121</s> 112 bytes

```latex
\input tikz\footline{}\tikz\draw[draw=none,fill=red](0,1)\foreach~ in{1,2,3}{[rotate=~*120]arc(0:60:\r pt)};\bye
```

The code is based on [this answer at TeX.se](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/160705/28808).

TeX is vector-based, so doesn't do pixels.  The radius is a float with a maximum of about 15 before it hits the edge of the page.  It's also not really built for commandline input, so need to be run as

```latex
pdftex  "\def\r{2} \input rt.tex"
```

where the code above is saved in `rt.tex`

Comment: A few tips to make this shorter: you don't need any of the newlines; you don't need `.tex`; `\footline{}` is just as good as `\nopagenumbers`; use `~` as a variable name instead of `\i`. To satisfy the “pixel” requirement, you could use `\r sp`; 1sp is the sort-of equivalent to a pixel for TeX since it's the finest location TeX can manage (I don't know if it applies to tikz though).

Comment: @Gilles I can't get anything with `sp` but I think `pt` is a good idea.  All your other ideas worked (some hadn't seemed to in my tests). Thank you

Comment: You can remove the space after `~` to save one more byte. `\input tikz\footline{}\tikz\draw[draw=none,fill=red](0,1)\foreach~in{1,2,3}{[rotate=~*120]arc(0:60:\r sp)};\bye` works for me. Try `pdftex  "\def\r{2000000} \input rt.tex"` — at 2sp finding the shape visually would be difficult given how small it is.

Comment: @Gilles I must admit I only went up to 20000 sp.

Comment: 1pt = 65536sp so 20000sp is still tiny.

Comment: You can save at least 25 bytes:
`\input tikz\def~#1{{[rotate=#1*60]arc(0:60:\r pt)}}\footline{}\tikz\fill(0,)~2~4~6;\bye`.
You can save one byte more by calling the input parameter \1 instead of \r, saving you the space: `\input tikz\def~#1{{[rotate=#1*60]arc(0:60:\1pt)}}\footline{}\tikz\fill(0,)~2~4~6;\bye`. I'd also say, but this is my personal opinion, that you do not really need `\footline{}` as it does not say "nothing but" the triangle. Anyways, this is a matter of taste. :-)

Answer (score 6):

## PHP+SVG, 165 bytes

```
<?$h=3/8*$w=2*$d=2*$r=$_GET[0];$q=$r+sqrt($r**2-($r/2)**2);echo"<svg width=$w height=$w><path d='M$r,$r A$r,$r 0 0 1 $d,$r A$r,$r 0 0 1 $h,$q A$r,$r 0 0 1 $r,$r'/>";
```

### Example Output for Input 128

```html
<svg width=512 height=512><path d='M128,128 A128,128 0 0 1 256,128 A128,128 0 0 1 192,238.85125168441 A128,128 0 0 1 128,128'/>
```

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, <s>134</s> 131 bytes

**N.B.** This solution is no longer valid, as the question was later edited to require *r* to be measured in pixels.  Thanks to Martin Ender for helping me shave off a few bytes in the comments.

```
r=Input[];RegionPlot[And@@((Abs[y+I x-#]^2<3r^2)&/@Table[Exp[2n I/3Pi]r,{n,3}]),{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1},Frame->False,BoundaryStyle->None]
```

[image]

The input value must be scaled between 0 and 1 for this code to work.  Note that almost a quarter of this code is required to display the shape "in isolation", as this is not Mathematica's default.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! `r Exp[2 I Pi n/3]` can be `Exp[2I n/3Pi]r` to save some spaces. And it's generally shorter to write an unnamed function, i.e. drop the `r=Input[];`, replace `r` with `#` and append a `&`.

Comment: I think the input has to be pixels, not a scaling factor.

Comment: @pycoder:  Yes, that constraint was edited in after I posted my solution.

Answer (score 4):

## BBC BASIC, 58 bytes

```
I.r:L.r,r,r,r:F.i=0TO9S.PI/1.5PLOT177,r*COS(i),r*SIN(i)N.
```

Download interpreter at http://www.bbcbasic.co.uk/bbcwin/download.html

**Ungolfed**

```
INPUTr                       :REM input a radius
LINEr,r,r,r                  :REM draw a line of length 0 from r,r to r,r to establish a cursor history away from the corner of the screen
FORi=0 TO 9 STEP PI/1.5      :REM in steps of 120 degrees (going round and round the three sides of an equilateral triangle)
  PLOT177,r*COS(i),r*SIN(i)  :REM move relative by r*COS(i),r*SIN(i) and draw a sector with arc between new and last graphics cursor positions,
NEXT                         :REM with the centre of the arc at the penultimate graphics cursor position.
```

Comment: Wow, that's practially a built-in!

Answer (score 3):

### GLSL, <s>298</s> 229 characters

```
precision lowp float;
uniform vec2 resolution;float r=100.;void main(){vec2 p=gl_FragCoord.xy-resolution.xy/2.;float h=sqrt(3.)/4.*r;gl_FragColor=vec4(length(p+vec2(r/2.,h))<r&&length(p+vec2(-r/2.,h))<r&&length(p-vec2(0.,h))<r);}
```

[Try it here](http://glslsandbox.com/e#40956.5)

[Bonus](http://glslsandbox.com/e#40956.7)

- Radius can be set by changing `r` variable
- Triangle width is in pixels as requested (you have to make zoom is set to 1x in GLSL sandbox).

Comment: Does GLSL have a standard input method you could use?

Comment: In glslsandbox, it is possible to get mouse cursor position. This could be used to control triangle radius (eg : radius would be mouse distance from center).

Answer (score 3):

### [Java + `Processing`](http://openjdk.java.net/), 95 bytes

```java
noStroke();arc(r,r,r,r,0,PI/3);arc(r+r/2,r,r,r,2*PI/3,PI);arc(r+r/4,r+r/2.3,r,r,4*PI/3,5*PI/3);
```

Takes input as variable r, outputs a Reuleaux triangle at \$(r,r)\$, given an adequately sized canvas.

[Code](https://tio.run/##y0osS9TNL0jNy0rJ/v8/Lz@4pCg/O1VD0zqxKFmjSAcCDXQCPPWNoWLaRfpGUHEjLZA4UBIhZaIDVqBnDFZgAlFgqgXR//8/AA)

#### As a function with size call, 124 bytes

```java
void a(int r){size(r*2,r*2);noStroke();arc(r,r,r,r,0,PI/3);arc(r+r/2,r,r,r,2*PI/3,PI);arc(r+r/4,r+r/2.3,r,r,4*PI/3,5*PI/3);}
```

#### Outputs

50

[image]

100

[image]

200

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) + HTML, 196 + 13 = 209 bytes

Uses a path-based approach instead of a pixel-filling approach.

```
r=>{c.width=c.height=r*2
with(Math)with(c.getContext`2d`)scale(e=r*.578,e),beginPath(a=s=>s*PI/3),moveTo(2,1),[2,4,6].map(s=>arcTo(cos(i=a(s-1))+1,sin(i)+1,cos(j=a(s))+1,sin(j)+1,sqrt(3))),fill()}
```

```
<canvas id=c>
```

```js
f=
r=>{c.width=c.height=r*2
with(Math)with(c.getContext`2d`)scale(e=r*.578,e),beginPath(a=s=>s*PI/3),moveTo(2,1),[2,4,6].map(s=>arcTo(cos(i=a(s-1))+1,sin(i)+1,cos(j=a(s))+1,sin(j)+1,sqrt(3))),fill()}

f(200)

//r=>{c.width=c.height=r*2
//with(Math)with(c.getContext`2d`)translate(r,r),scale(r,r),beginPath(a=s=>s*PI/3),S=sqrt(3),moveTo(1/S,0),[2,4,6].map(s=>arcTo(cos(i=a(s-1))/S,sin(i)/S,cos(j=a(s))/S,sin(j)/S,1)),fill()}

//r=>{c.width=c.height=r*2
//with(Math)with(c.getContext`2d`)translate(r,r),scale(r,r),beginPath(),P=PI/2,A=(s,_)=>(_?sin:cos)(s*PI/3)/sqrt(3),moveTo(A(0),0),[2,4,6].map(s=>arcTo(A(s-1),A(s-1,1),A(s),A(s,1),1)),fill()}
```

```html
<canvas id=c>
```

Answer (score 2):

## Logo, 53 bytes

```
to t :r filled 0[repeat 3[arc 60 :r fd :r rt 120]]end
```

uses the `filled` command to fill the shape in colour 0 (black.) The code in the outer  square brackets is executed without any line being drawn, but Logo keeps track of the turtle movements and fills in the shape once the bracket is exited.

## Logo, <s>64</s> 61 bytes

```
to t :r repeat 3[pd arc 60 :r pu fd :r rt 120]fd 9 fill end
```

Pen Down, draw 60 degree arc with turtle at the centre, Pen Up, move pen to start of arc, turn 120 deg.

Repeat 3 times, then move inside the shape and fill it.

Try at http://turtleacademy.com/playground/en

Call like `cs ht t 100` (clear screen, hide turtle, `t` with r=100.)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 35 bytes

```
9Bo&ZQ*3X^/G_G&:t!J*+8L&!-|G<A&e0YG
```

This produces a file called `image.png`. For input `r`, the size of the image is `2*r+1`, and the width of the triangle is `r` as required.

Try it at [**MATL Online!**](https://matl.io/?code=9Bo%26ZQ%2a3X%5E%2FG_G%26%3At%21J%2a%2B8L%26%21-%7CG%3CA%26e0YG&inputs=100&version=20.1.1) The online interpreter automatically opens the created file and displays the image with arbitrary scaling; click on it to obtain the actual-size version.

Alternatively, here are two example outputs from the offline compiler running on Matlab,  with inputs `50` and  `100`. The last part of the code `0YG` has been replaced by `IYG` so that the figure is directly displayed (with the right size) instead of written to a file.

[image]

#### Explanation

```
9B      % Push 9 in binary: [1 0 0 1] with logical values
o       % Convert to double
&ZQ     % Roots of polynomial with coefficients [1 0 0 1], as a 3×1 column vector
*       % Multiply by implicit input r
3X^/    % Divide by sqrt(3). This gives a 3×1 vector with the circle centers
G_G&:   % Push row vector [-r -r+1 ... r-1 r], with size 1×(2*r+1)
t!J*    % Duplicate, transpose, multiply by 1j
+       % Add with broadcast. This gives a (2*r+1)×(2*r+1) 2D-array of complex
        % numbers, which defines the pixel grid
8L      % Push [3 1 2]
&!      % Permute dimensions as indicated. This gives a 1×(2*r+1)×(2*r+1) 3D-array
-|      % Subtract with broadcast. Absolute value. This gives a 3×(2*r+1)×(2*r+1)
        % 3D-array with the distance from each circle center to each grid point
G<      % Less than r? Gives a 3×(2*r+1)×(2*r+1) 3D-array containing true or false
A       % All: this gives a 1×(2*r+1)×(2*r+1) array containing true for
        % columns of the original 3D-array that contained all true values
&e      % Squeeze the first singleton dimension to give a (2*r+1)×(2*r+1) 2D-array
0YG     % Save as image file with default file name
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6) + SVG (HTML5), 28 + 102 = 130 bytes

```js
f=
n=>s.setAttribute('width',n)
```

```html
<input type=number value=82 oninput=f(this.value)><br>
<svg id=s width=82 viewbox=0,0,82,82><path d=M0,71a82,82,0,0,0,82,0A82,82,0,0,0,41,0A82,82,0,0,0,0,71>
```

Byte count excludes code needed for convenient user input of desired size.

Comment: Clever! `n=>s.style.width=n` would work also.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how you came to 112 bytes.

Comment: @darrylyeo That suggestion didn't work for me, sorry, but I agree about the byte count, I can't figure out how I came to it either.

Comment: Hmm, probably only works in Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

## MetaPost (<s>242</s> 226 Bytes)

```
outputtemplate:="%j-%c.ps";
prologues:=1
beginfig(1);
 len:=1cm;
 path p[];
 p[1]:=len * dir -30 {dir 90} .. len * dir  90;
 p[2]:=p[1] rotated 120;
 p[3]:=p[1] rotated 240;
 fill p[1] -- p[2] -- p[3] -- cycle;
endfig;
end.
```

It may be possible to reduce this somewhat, I'm new to metapost.

Comment: I was a bit lazy and used the text editors byte count. I didn't know you could remove the colons, Thanks. I literally have an hour of MetaPost under the belt now ^_^

Comment: I still count 223, not 226. Also, can you remove the spaces in `len * dir` and the dot at the end?

Answer (score 1):

## k, <s>141</s> <s>100</s> 98 bytes

```
s:*/2#;l:2*r:.:0:`
`0:(,"P1")," "/'$(,l,l),&/{(s'n+x)</:(s r)-s'y+n:r-!l}./:r*%(0 0;4 0;1 3)%4
\\
```

Input is taken from `stdin`, output is `stderr` (or `stdin` depending on the interpreter) in `pgm` format. For example:

[image: Example of the program working.]

Explanation:

```
s:*/2#               /set s to a squaring function
r:.:0:`              /get user input, set to r
l:2*                 /width/height is 2 times r
r*%(0 0;4 0;1 3)%4   /the coordinates of circle centers
{ }./:               /for each coordinate pair (x, y) get a circle
                     /function to get a circle:
n:r-!l               /  set n to {r, r-1, ..., -(r-1)}
(s'n+x)</:(s r)-s'y+ /  use b^2<r^2-a^2 on all points to get a circle
                     /  where x and y shift the circle right and down
&/                   /get intersections of circles (fold binary and)
(,l,l),              /prepend height and width for PGM format
" "/'$               /convert to string, add spaces
(,"P1"),             /prepend PGM header
`0:                  /output to stderr
\\                   /exit
```

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 66 bytes

```
’)
¨€(ÿ,60)
lt(60’Ð’€š éà £Ø*
ht()
ï…_œã(ÿÿÿ)
„–_œã()
„ˆ 1:ht()’.e
```

Can't use TIO, since it opens a window and draws the Reuleaux triangle there.

Asks for input, and then opens up a Python turtle window drawing the triangle.

Jonathan Allan's answer gave me the inspiration to do this, although I altered his code a bit.

Essentially, this is a combination of 05AB1E's compressing capabilities and Python's ease of turtle graphics.

Answer (score 1):

### [OpenSCAD](http://www.openscad.org/), 91 bytes

```
module t(r){intersection_for(t=[0,120,240]){rotate(t)translate([r/sqrt(3),0,0])circle(r);}}
```

I'm not sure how kosher this is, as pixels aren't really a well-defined unit in any mesh grid formats that I know of. In stead, the module `t` draws a reuleaux triangle of given radius `r` in whatever native units are in use.

Sample preview output for `t(100)`:
[image: t(100)]

Answer (score 1):

## SmileBASIC, <s>87</s> <s>86</s> <s>85</s> <s>83</s> <s>82</s> <s>81</s> <s>79</s> <s>78</s> <s>77</s> <s>76</s> 75 bytes

```
INPUT R
C.5Y=R*.87C 1C.GPAINT.,0DEF C X
A=X*240GCIRCLE R*X,Y+2,R,A-60,A
END
```

### Ungolfed:

```
INPUT RADIUS
CIRCLE 0.5
Y=RADIUS*(SQR(3)/2)
CIRCLE 1
CIRCLE 0
GPAINT 0,0
DEF CIRCLE X
 ANGLE=X*240
 GCIRCLE RADIUS*X,Y+2,RADIUS,ANGLE-60,ANGLE
END
```